# Are reaction time and memory physiological measure or behavioral observation?

Tags: behavior, behaviorism, physiology, reaction-time

I think that the choice made by a subject in a choice task should be behavioral observation. But I am not sure about reaction time and memory, which is more about ability instead of intention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may help considering whether the phenomenon is under some  control by the participant. Pupil dilation is a physiological measure, but the speed at which I hit a key (reaction time) is a behavioral measure. Memory is a phenomenon. If you meant recall, recognition, or another memory retrieval task, how could you measure that physiologically? Memory is generally measured through (somewhat controlled) self-report. However, it could also be probed through less controllable, more automatic reactions.

Comment: So should memory be counted as "self-report" instead of behavioral measure?

Comment: What about eye movement and gaze duration?

Comment: If you ask people "how much did you remember“ then you have a self-report of memory, if you test people on some memory items you probably have a behavioral measure. There are many ways to probe memory, also many types of memory, pretty sure you could have a physiological measure of familiarity/recognition if you wanted one (and could spend money on the gear to measure it!)

Comment: Why is it important to distinguish between different kinds of measure/observation though? So long as you have a question and answer it anything is fine?

Comment: agree with @steveLangsford above: to classify something as self-report, behavioral, etc. one needs to decide on a specific measure. Eye movements are medium-controllable, so that might be a mix, depending on what the participant's task and intentions are.